# Script does not update screen in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I created the script below for the screen to scroll down into an extensive spreadsheet developed in google spreadsheets. I left the script runtime in 4 minutes because of the limitation of running google spreadsheet scripts and created a trigger that runs this same script every 5 minutes. The problem is that the script when executed by the trigger runs in the background and does not scroll down as when it runs manually. Note: I'm using the AppScript extension.

```
function scrollTable() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var totalRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var initialTime= new Date().getTime();
  var duration= 4 * 60 * 1000; // 4 min

  while (new Date().getTime() - initialTime< duration) {

    for (var i = 1; i <= (totalRows - rows + 1); i += 4) {
        sheet.setActiveRange(sheet.getRange(i, rows));
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        Utilities.sleep(2000);
        if (new Date().getTime() - initialTime>= duration) {
          break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If there are no pending spreadsheet changes then SpreadsheetApp.flush does nothing.  As far as I can see your script does nothing.  Which is what you are seeing so all is well.

Comment: I inserted the code snippet "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(1);" within the while to check if this was the problem. It changes cell A1 as expected, but does not scroll down

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem but I think this code is incorrect.

It will always compare the value of `initialTime >= duration`, which is most likely `true`.  So `i` is always 1.

```
while (new Date().getTime() - initialTime< duration) {

  if (new Date().getTime() - initialTime>= duration) {
```

I think what you want is to subtract `initialTime` from current time and compare to `duration`.

```
while( (new Date().getTime() - initialTime) < duration) {

  if( (new Date().getTime() - initialTime) >= duration) {
```

Comment: the script is working when I run it manually, the screen goes down. The problem is by the trigger, the screen does not go down

Comment: Your if statement subtracts a Boolean from a Number.  `new Date().getTime()` returns a Number.  `initialTime>= duration` most likely return `true`.  Subtract a Boolean from a Number and you are either subtracting 0 (false) or (1) true.  So 1 will be subtracted from the Number and the if condition is satisfied and the break will occur when `i` is 1

Comment: I understand, but my problem is not in running the code, it is running flawlessly. My problem is that when run by the scheduler, only by the trigger the screen does not scroll down.

Comment: Please just make the changes I've identified and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, I've done as you mentioned, but the error still persists

Comment: I changed the code just for testing, removed the part of the code that limits the start and end time to 4 minutes and kept only the action of going down the screen, Waited for the automatic trigger, but still persists the error. The screen does not go down alone when it is run by the auto trigger, it only works when run manually.

Comment: Everytime the trigger runs, whether manually or timed it will write to the Execution Log.  Do you see any errors?

Comment: Apparently does not display execution failures, the log appears as Complete and the current appears as Running

Comment: i made the spreadsheet available so they can check

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15QewTJjO3DgaZoW4uAGmLKjnIbW30S_ISZCEPWNXsAo/edit#gid=1115838130